# 'poedit' translation activation

Tags: wordpress, translation, poedit

I'm trying to make my wordpress site translation ready, using 'poedit'. I have problems with activating the translation. I want to translate the site only, not wordpress system. I have my .pot, .po and .mo files in a 'languages' folder in my theme directory, I have this code in my functions.php file:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'example', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

well, after everything is saved and translated in the poedit program, how do I activate it in my site? I am working with a localhost for now.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to connect the method to an action hook in your theme functions.php:

```
function load_mytheme_textdomain() {
    load_theme_textdomain( 'example', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'load_mytheme_textdomain' );
```

Then you have to use translation instead of echo for output:

```
_e( 'My Text', 'example' );
```

Read more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/